# useEffect exhaustive-deps rule is confusing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

I have found a few questions related to this on stackoverflow, but nothing that satisfies a use-case which I have very regularly while using `useEffect`. Let's say I have some code like this:

```js
const ApiViewer = (props) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('')

    useEffect(async () => {
        setResult(await callApi(props.valueThatWillChangeButIOnlyCareAboutItsInitialValue))
    }, [])

    return <div>{result}</div>
}
```

The `exhaustive-deps` rule will throw, asking me to put `props.valueThatWillChangeButIOnlyCareAboutItsInitialValue` in the dependency array. I don't want to do this as I only want the initial value. I may use that prop in a separate effect somewhere.

I can't think of another way to write this either.

I also have the problem that other people seem to have, i.e. using functions/etc that I know will never change. I don't want to add them to this array, seems very dumb.

Dan Abramov said that **Usually disabling it is a mistake and will significantly bite you later**. I've been using it this way for years and I've seen no issues until this rule started popping up in a new project.

Am I using React completely wrong?

Comment: "I also have the problem that other people seem to have, i.e. using functions/etc that I know will never change. I don't want to add them to this array, seems very dumb." You can move the functions that "don't change" out of the scope where they are redeclared each render cycle ***or*** you can simply memoize them and add them to the dependency array anyway since they'll now be stable references. Don't disable the React hooks linting rules, it'll likely cause more harm than good over just adding a `// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` comment to the ones you want to ignore.

Comment: [This comment](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6880#issuecomment-486875202) from the thread you linked is the best one, IMHO. And it mentions an issue I've been hit by before. You navigate from `/thing/1` to `/thing/2` and the `ThingDashboard` component is used at both routes. Since the DOM hasn't changed meaningfully, a new instance of that component is not created, but the one from the previous render now has different props or context values. Anything that runs "on mount" will not run at this point, and that could be a big and confusing problem to have and diagnose.

Comment: > valueThatWillChangeButIOnlyCareAboutItsInitialValue

If it changed, it has a new initial value that you should care about just as much as the previous initial value. The consumer of your component changed it for a reason. If your initial values got changed, they must be expecting you to re-initialize.

As for things that you know will never change, add them to the array. It's free and it avoids having to disable the rule. Ignoring the rule when things *do* change is almost always a bug, and leaving it enabled notifies you later if you add a dependency and forget to add it to the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Treating "exhaustive deps" as the true rule that it is will ensure components update as expected.

If you want to ignore updates to a given prop you can clarify that by using a `useRef`. You won't get any warnings inside a `useEffect` because the base object returned from `useRef` never changes. Using an `initial` prefix will make this obvious to the next developer as well.

```js
const ApiViewer = (props) => {
    const [result, setResult] = useState('')
    const initialValueThatWillChangeRef = useRef(props.valueThatWillChange);

    useEffect(async () => {
        setResult(await callApi(initialValueThatWillChangeRef.current))
    }, [])

    return <div>{result}</div>
}
```

You can construct examples where everything works as expected by ignoring the "exhaustive deps" rule, but you will eventually run into a nuanced case that breaks for reasons that are difficult to debug.

Comment: This is a good tip but it's missing a part: you need an effect to update the value of the ref:

```
const initialValueThatWillChangeRef = useRef(props.valueThatWillChange);
useEffect(() => {
  initialValueThatWillChangeRef.current = props.valueThatWillChange
})
```

edit: apologies for formatting

Comment: @mikewyatt OP said he wanted the initial value of the prop, hence why I ignored any updates to it.

Comment: and why would you do that and not just disable this rule? Do you know KISS principle?

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you are doing it right! Exhaustive dep is just a warning thrown by eslint, and just because you got the warning it doesn't mean you are doing it completely wrong. If your code demands something to be run only on the initial load of the component, what you are doing it completely right.

Although I would suggest you don't remove this rule completely and to just suppress them where ever necessary.

EDIT: The reason I said not to completely disable the rule was because, other hooks like `useCallback` and `useMemo` also works based on dependency list. And if you failed to add your dependency list for those hooks, it can completely backfire on you.

Having the warning is always good, because you are not the only one who's gonna be working on a project, this can also help a new junior developer that you hire tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @DaraJava, I have edited my answer :)

Comment: Downvoted because this is a dangerous suggestion. The exhaustive deps rule is truly a rule; you should not ignore it.

Comment: @RossAllen this is categorically false in older versions of React. The creation of useEffectEvent to get around valid use cases of non-exhaustive deps is a clear admission of this.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for pointing that out. I read through the docs for [`useEffectEvent`](https://react.dev/learn/separating-events-from-effects#declaring-an-effect-event) and understand what you mean, there are instances where you have a dependency you want to indicate as non-reactive. Back when I answered React q's more frequently the folks who wanted to ignore `useEffect` really shouldn't have, seemed safer to stress following the rule. Agreed there were always cases where the rule should have been broken though.